# hide certain module in certain page

Tags: php, opencart

in search result page I want to exclude my custom module from showing. I want it to be displayed in home only. It seems the panel not have the option to do that.

The quick hack would be display none using js, but that's not a good solution.

Comment: what did you try so far? Can you elaborate more your question.

Comment: @HTTP I tried to create a new layout with system->design->layout and then expect I can drag away the unwanted elements in Theme Control Panel. But I can add module but not remove it.

Comment: @HTTP I fixed that. I miss entered the route. It should be just /search

Comment: @user3522457 Please, make your comment into a little bit more descriptive answer while answering your question and accepting your own answer. This way you could help somebody else in the future...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go into admin and into design/layouts and create a new layout called home.

You will then open the module and edit it so that it is only selected on the home layout.

You will then go into settings and into the store and then select the layout for the home page as "home"  (or the new one you just created). Cheers
Jeremy